# Using variables in OOP PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, image

I'm new to OOP and [I'm using this tutorial to resize images](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362), but I can't get it to work. I'm uploading images with [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com).

My code looks like this:

```
include_once '../core/init.php';
$username = $user['username']; 

$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$storeFolder = '../users'; 

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];        

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds . $username . $ds;

    $tempName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $kaboom = explode(".", $tempName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);
    $filename = date("DMj-Y-G-i-s-")."".rand(1000,9999).".".$fileExt;

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $filename;

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    include("image_resize.php");
    $resizeObj = new resize($targetPath . $targetFile);
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(550, 550, 'crop');
    $resizeObj -> saveImage($targetPath.'medium-'.$targetFile, 100);

    $users->upload_image($username, $filename, $time, $ip);

}
```

**What works:** the image is successfully uploaded and moved to the correct directory. `$user->upload_image` works and inserts the new image data into my database.

**What doesn't work:** the `image_resize` doesn't work. The demo from the tutorial works fine, but when I change the `sample.jpg` out for my `targetPath` and `targetFile`, nothing happens. I'm trying to create a duplicate image that's 550x550pixels with `medium-` added before the file name, but nothing is happening.

Comment: Do you know if it uses something like ImageMagick as a dependency that you may not have installed on your environment?

Comment: The example in the tutorial works, so I know that the resize class works. There's something wrong with how I'm using it.

Comment: `$users->upload_image` - where is the `$users` object instantiated?

Comment: In init.php ... all it does it update the database, and it works fine.

Comment: `$kaboom` really lool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some inconsistencies in your file paths, here you're prepending `$targetPath` to `$targetFile`:

```
$targetFile =  $targetPath. $filename;
```

Then you upload the file using `$targetFile` - which already contains `$targetPath`:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

So then when you try and resize it, you're prepending the `$targetPath` variable **again**:

```
$resizeObj = new resize($targetPath . $targetFile);
```

Try that line without `$targetPath`:

```
$resizeObj = new resize($targetFile);
```

**EDIT:** noticed you're using `$targetPath` again when saving the thumbnail, so in this case you'll actually need to keep those two variables separate, only combining them when necessary - because when you save, you're putting `$targetPath`, then `medium-` then the filename which already contains `$targetPath`.

Keep the path and the filename separate, and try this:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetPath . $filename);

include("image_resize.php");
$resizeObj = new resize($targetPath . $filename);
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(550, 550, 'crop');
$resizeObj -> saveImage($targetPath . 'medium-' . $filename, 100);
```